# type error when using class inheritence

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, typeerror

I have the following code:

```
class SphericalRefraction(OpticalElement):
    def __init__(self, r0, normal, curvature, n, h):
        self._r0 = r0
        self._normal = normal/npl.norm(normal)
        self._curvature = curvature
        self._n = n
        self._aperture = h

def OutputPlane(SphericalRefraction):
    def __init__(self, r0, normal, h=15):
        SphericalRefraction.__init__(self, r0=r0, normal=normal, curvature=0, n=1, h=h)
```

But when I construct a class OutputPlane in my `main`:

```
screen = r.OutputPlane(np.array([0,0,f]),np.array([0,0,1]), 5)
```

I have the following error:

```
TypeError: OutputPlane() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

What have I done wrong? What should I do so that I can inherit OutputPlane from SphericalRefraction?

Comment: What is `r` here in `r.OutputPlane(..`?

Comment: You do not show sufficient code.

Comment: Your `OutputPlane` is a function (declared with `def`). I guess you wanted to use `class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not inheriting `SphericalRefraction` because you have defined `OutputPlane` like a function and not like a class.

So `def OutputPlane(SphericalRefraction):`
should be
`class OutputPlane(SphericalRefraction):`

Comment: what a stupid mistake I have made... thanks for help anyway

Answer (score 5):

Change:

```
def OutputPlane(SphericalRefraction):
```

into:

```
class OutputPlane(SphericalRefraction):
```

an you should be good to go.